# SSH key authentication works with /usr/sbin/ssh -d, does not with the daemon?

Tags: ssh, centos, sshd, key-authentication

CentOS x64 6.5: if I connect as `root` to my server and do the following:

```
service sshd stop
/usr/sbin/ssh -d
```

I'll able to connect as user using public key authentication from my development machine:

```
ssh -v user@myserver.mydomain.com
```

When however I use the daemon:

```
service sshd start
```

I'm not able to connect anymore, and ssh asks for a password. `tail -f /var/log/secure` shows nothing.

Have you any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Run the client with multiple `v` to see more debugging info, as in `-vvv`. It may give you a clue.

Comment: also try running "/usr/sbin/sshd -De" instead of "-d" - debug mode has several differences to normal daemon mode.

Comment: @Dani_l running `/usr/sbin/sshd -De` and trying to connect works fine: *Accepted public key for user from 192.168.1.134 port 55803 ssh2*. But after running service sshd start, the same client can't connect.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Centos [bug](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=6468?).

Deleting first line "`#!/bin/bash`" from `/etc/init.d/sshd` fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at your processes - do they contain sshd?

```
ps -eF | grep ssh
```

Please check the output of the command mentioned above before and after stopping/starting the service. Maybe something goes wrong, when starting the daemon.

Comment: Nothing special after running that command. Any help?